# Installing from Tar.gz Permission Denied

Tags: permissions, tar, archive

Total Linux noob. I have worked in the WinTel world as a network/sys admin for going on twenty years. Its time for me to get my feet wet with Ubuntu.

Let me preface this with the following: I have googled this and just can't make any head way. Each question just leads me into another rabbit hole. I have looked and looked and keep getting frustrated. So please forgive my noob question(s).

I am attempting to install OpenFire from tar.gz without success. I saved the archive to my desktop and am attempting to unzip the folder(s) to either /opt or /usr/bin as indicated by the OF documentation. I keep getting permission denied. Is this something you can help with?

Using Desktop version 12.04 LTS inside Oracle VirtualBox most current release.

Thanks for any info.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are talking of this [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/)?

Comment: What error are you getting ? (e.g. like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LaDQE.png)?) Please add a screenshot (use http://imgur.com) or the error output to your question

Answer (score 1):

Better to go to [igniterealtime.org](http://igniterealtime.org/downloads/index.jsp#openfire) and download the .deb package for Ubuntu - you'll have much less trouble during installation.